# Golang lock-free array with swap

Tags: go, lock-free

I have a two slot array that need to swap between slots when producer set it and always return a valid slot to consumer. As for side of atomic operation logic I can't imagine situation when two goroutine write to the same array slot, but race detector think otherwise. Does anyone can explain me, where is the bug?

```
type checkConfig struct {
    timeout   time.Time
}

type checkConfigVersions struct {
    config [2]*checkConfig
    reader uint32
    writer uint32
}

func (c *checkConfigVersions) get() *checkConfig {
    return c.config[atomic.LoadUint32(&c.reader)]
}

func (c *checkConfigVersions) set(new *checkConfig) {
    for {
        reader := atomic.LoadUint32(&c.reader)
        writer := atomic.LoadUint32(&c.writer)
        switch diff := reader ^ writer; {
        case diff == 0:
            runtime.Gosched()
        case diff == 1:
            if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&c.writer, writer, (writer+1)&1) {
                c.config[writer] = new
                atomic.StoreUint32(&c.reader, writer)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data race happened on `c.config[writer] = new`, but for my point of view it's not possible.

```
fun main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ccv := &checkConfigVersions{reader: 0, writer: 1}

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        wg.Add(100)
        go func(i int) {
            for j := 0; j < 100; j++ {
                ccv.set(&checkConfig{})
                wg.Done()
            }
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(ccv.get())
}
```

Data race detector output:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c42009a020 by goroutine 12:
  main.(*checkConfigVersions).set()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:118 +0xd9
  main.main.func1()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:42 +0x60

Previous write at 0x00c42009a020 by goroutine 11:
  main.(*checkConfigVersions).set()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:118 +0xd9
  main.main.func1()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:42 +0x60

Goroutine 12 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:40 +0x159

Goroutine 11 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/apple/Documents/Cyber/Go/proxy/main.go:40 +0x159
==================
```

And if you try to read it with `ccv.read()`, you catch the another race but between *read* and *write* on the same array slot...

Comment: You should include the race detector output.

Comment: Your goroutines will be stepping all over each other between the `LoadUint32` and the `CompareAndSwapUint32`, so yes, this is very very racy. You should really just have a mutex, just because you're reading and writing a value atomically does not mean that you're preventing anyone else from reading and writing them.

Comment: If goroutine step each other they collide on CAS, and CAS reads a new value of &c.write and if it not the same as when reading, then simply read it again in cycle... It exactly mean that you can't write because of "write index" that you push father on array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can change your code to check the just-written `c.writer`:

```
if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&c.writer, writer, (writer+1)&1) {
  newWriter := atomic.LoadUint32(&c.writer)
  if newWriter != (writer+1)&1 {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("wrote %d, but writer is %d", (writer+1)&1, newWriter))
  }
  //c.config[writer] = new
  atomic.StoreUint32(&c.reader, writer)
  return
}
```

Manually setting `GOMAXPROCS` (and the number of goroutines) to just 3, I get the following after running it just a few times:

```
$ go run main.go  
panic: wrote 1, but writer is 0

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.(*checkConfigVersions).set(0xc42000a060, 0x1, 0xc4200367a0)
    main.go:36 +0x16d
main.main.func1(0xc42000a060, 0xc420018110, 0x1)
    main.go:58 +0x63
created by main.main
    main.go:56 +0xd6
exit status 2
```

The main reason is that `GOMAXPROCS` sets the number of OS threads to use. These are not controlled by Go (Go just schedules goroutines onto OS threads). Instead, the OS gets to schedule OS threads however it wants.

This means that one of the goroutines will `CAS(1, 1, 0)`, then be suspended by the OS. During that time, another goroutine will go through and `CAS(0, 0, 1)`. This allows the third goroutine to perform `CAS(1, 1, 0)` and continues at the same time as the original goroutine is scheduled for execution again. Bam! Both of them are trying to write to the same `config[writer]`.

Atomicity is great when you want to avoid a mutex, but should not be used to perform synchronization in this type of case.

I'm not quite sure what your original scenario is, but I'm fairly confident going with a mutex will save you a lot of pain.